# How to get accessKeyLabel in WebKit with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, accessibility, access-keys

[accessKeyLabel](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#dom-accesskeylabel) from what I can tell is not supported in Webkit (but works fine in Firefox) at the time of writing. [This snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/szlxm) shows what happens:

```
<input type="text" accesskey="D" name="dog" id="dog">

var dogInput = document.getElementById('dog');

console.log(dogInput.accessKey);
// Firefox, Webkit both output: "D"

console.log(dogInput.accessKeyLabel);
// Firefox output: "[ACCESS MODIFIER] D"
// Webkit output: undefined
```

Is there another way of getting the access modifier combination or accessKeyLabel in Webkit?

Comment: This attribute hasn't been landed to webkit. Please refer "https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72715".

Answer (score 0):

This is an unimplemented feature (known bug) in WebKit:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72715