# Getting the key combination of accesskeys in a browser

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a page where certain inputs and links have accesskeys attached to them, and I want to inform the user of what key combination they need to press to activate the input or link. Is there a way to automatically get the accesskey key combination of a browser via JavaScript, or do I need to detect which browser it is and then just use a table where I store the key combination that browser uses?

I haven't found any scripts that could automatically detect this (I've looked at the source code for Wikipedia, and they also go by browser name), which I find curious, since most sites seem to recommend feature detection as opposed to browser detection. I would find it weird if accesskeys would be the exception to that.

Also, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key), there's a huge load of different key combinations for accesskeys, so I don't think making an array of combinations and picking the browser's combination would be the best solution for that.

Comment: @SergeiZahharenko what do you mean?

Comment: I would explicitly [specify the `accesskey` for each item](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-accesskey-attribute). Then your JS can access it like a normal attribute, and it will be consistent across browsers and platforms.

Comment: @Phrogz That is indeed what I am doing, but the problem isn't getting what the actual accesskey is, but getting what key combination activates the accesskey in each specific browser. For Chrome on Windows, this is ALT+SHIFT, for IE it is ALT, for browsers on Mac it's a lot of different things. I need to detect which key combination activates the accesskey.

Comment: By the way, I just found this [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16623329/1256925), even though that one didn't get any answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per HTML5, there is a [JS attribute called `accessKeyLabel`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#dom-accesskeylabel) that should return a string appropriate to the browser, based on the value of the [`accesskey` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-accesskey-attribute).

This [may not work](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72715) across all browsers/versions that you care about, however, in which case you will need a manual browser-sniffing-and-branching fallback. 10–20 such combinations are not a "huge" amount IMHO, and the only reasonable recourse.

Comment: At first I thought this wasn't what I was looking for, but apparently it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your answer, and sorry for my slow processing of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

## State of accessKeyLabel in 2021

Since HTML 5, we've had the [`accessKeyLabel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/accessKeyLabel) property to read the actual keyboard shortcut assigned by the browser. Sadly, [browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlelement_accesskeylabel) is still too low to rely on it, since not only IE and Edge, but also Chrome are currently missing.

### Polyfill to the rescue

I had the exact same problem but required decent browser support, so I implemented a small polyfill to bridge the gap. It tries to detect feature support and if nothing is found, adds a small function that will return the correct modifier keys based on the User-Agent.

Installing the polyfill (less than 1KB):

```sh
npm i access-key-label-polyfill
```

Activation:

```js
import installAccessKeyLabelPolyfill from 'access-key-label-polyfill';
installAccessKeyLabelPolyfill();
```

Learn more about the polyfill here: https://github.com/tillsanders/access-key-label-polyfill

### Usage

Usage of the `accessKeyLabel` property is simple, **with and without** the polyfill. Assuming you have a button like this:

```html
<button accesskey="d">Do crazy stuff</button>
```

You can get the actual shortcut like this:

```js
const label = document.querySelector('#button').accessKeyLabel;
```

This might return a string like these:

```js
'⌃⌥d' // Chrome on macOS (only works with polyfill)
'⌃⌥d' // Safari on iOS (works without polyfill)
'Alt+Shift+d' // Firefox on Windows (works without polyfill)
'Alt+d' // Edge on Windows (only works with polyfill)
```

Be aware though, that in cases where the browser does not support `accessKeyLabel` (and you're not using the polyfill) or where the browser does not support `accessKey`, you will only get `undefined`.